# Which is better for sorting an arrayList of objects, Using the comparator or Merge sort?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I need to sort an arrayList. I can use a Comparator and override the compare function to sort. Or I can write a merge sort function on my own and sort the ArrayList.

I read somewhere that a comparator sorting uses bubble sort algorithm. Since Merge Sort has lesser complexity, do I go for merge sort over using a comparator which is easier to implement.

Comment: If you are sorting objects, java uses TimSort, which is a hybrid of mergesort and insertion sort ..

Comment: I'm trying to sort ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>. Sorting this uses TimSort?

Comment: @RaviShankar https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Someone told me bubble sort is being used and that confused me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Comparator to impose the total ordering of the objects in the ArrayList and use Collection.sort(List list, Comparator c) to sort the list. [Quoting the Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) for the above sort method, it uses an iterative mergesort algorithm adapted from Tim Peter's list sort for python (TimSort).